# How to 'convert' a Java REST call to a Postman REST call

Tags: java, postman

I'm having problems doing a Postman REST call copying a REST call in Java.

I tried to set request properties on Postman the same way they're set in Java, but it's not working.
I have to send a base64 string with this call (i put in italic the code line where this is done in Java code)

```
 URLConnection connection = new URL(url + content).openConnection();
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setUseCaches(false);
    connection.setConnectTimeout(timeout);
    ((HttpURLConnection) connection).setRequestMethod("POST");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "*/*");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");

    OutputStream output = connection.getOutputStream();

    JSONObject conf = new JSONObject();
    conf.put("signedEvidence", String.format("%s", baos));

    *output.write(conf.toString().getBytes());*
    output.flush();
    checkHttpStatus(connection);
```

I configured Postman like this:

[image]

And i receive this answer:

[image]

EDIT - In few words: the REST call works fine in Java, but i need to do some of these calls in Postman with my own variable (the service i'm calling do some works with base64 string i pass him).
EDIT2 - Main problem, in my opinion, is the line:

```
output.write(conf.toString().getBytes());
```

which set the base64 in my Java call, and i don't understand/know how to do the same in my Postman call.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?
What do you expect to see, and what are you seeing instead?
(Please answer these questions by editing the question, rather than in a comment)

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not working"? Are you getting errors? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask good questions.

Comment: i edited the question as soon as i posted, i forgot to say the base64 part

Comment: @Newwizard can you include the body section of your postman call in the question?

Comment: @Asankasanjaya i have no Body in Postman right now, do I have to paste my base64 there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try only adding the following values:

[image: add only these values]

Then, add the content type and the values which you need to pass.

[image: add the content type and the values which you need to pass here like this]